# ASP compare validator cannot take current date after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, comparevalidator

I made an asp.net 4.5 web form application. In my app, one `webform` has a `compare validatior` control. Here is my `aspx` code:

[image: aspx code snippet]

Here's my aspx.cs code for that validator:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");                
            ComparevalidatorDOB.ValueToCompare = currentDate;
        }
    }
```

It works fine on my PC. But when I published the `web form application` in [smarterasp](http://smarterasp.net); I get this error whenever I go the page using compare validator:

[image: error]

How can I solve this error?   **Please note that I'm getting this error after publishing the application. The app works fine in my visual studio 2017. And I can't use `javascript` for some particular reason.**

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem. Here it is...
I added the appropriate culture for date on the top of the page where the problem was occurring.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Culture="bn-BD" %>
```

Now my page works fine.

P.S: I found [this](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx) link very useful to determine which culture to use for different types of format.